# Get twitter tweet into javascript variable for display...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

This is going to be a bit more vague than usual as I am looking for direction and don't really have any code to share, yet.

On my business webpage there is a jquery plugin welcome message (growl style) that is populated by the text I have typed into the JS file.  In my hopes to make changing this text easier for my employees I was hoping I could somehow get my most recent tweet into a variable that I could then display automatically... this way there is no changing of code needed.

My hope was to somehow take a string like, "This is a title:this is the message" and be able to separate them into 2 different variable by means of the colon as a seperator.  Then I could display these variable using their var name.

This would be an example of the final product, minus the twitter parsing:

```
jQuery(function($) {
            $("#stdWelcome").ready(function(){
                growlwelcomeid = ("gs"+$.Growl._statsCount);
                $.Growl.show(TwitterMessage, {
                  'title'  : TwitterTitle,
                  'icon'   : "star",
                  'timeout': "10000",
                  'speed': "900"
                });
              });
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

So how would something like this look:

```
var Wusername = "username"; 
var Wurl = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/'+Wusername+'.json?callback=?'; 

$.getJSON(Wurl, function(tweet){ 
    $Wtitle = tweet[0].text.split('|');
}); 

jQuery(function($) {
            $("#stdWelcome").ready(function(){
                growlwelcomeid = ("gs"+$.Growl._statsCount);
                $.Growl.show(Wtitle[1], {
                  'title'  : Wtitle[0],
                  'icon'   : "star",
                  'timeout': "10000",
                  'speed': "900"
                });
              });
        });
```

Thanks again!

Comment: In the AjJAXcall to get the tweet, you get data as a return, so `data[0].text` would be the message of the first tweet. Not sure where the title is coming from though... You would need to call that assignment function from the AJAX success call though.

Comment: Yes that looks right apart from one thing, you name the variable `$Wtitle` but then try to access it using variable name `Wtitle`.  The `$` is important as it is part of the variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had the title and message as seperate tweets you could do the following

```
var username = "twitter username";
var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/'+username+'.json?callback=?';

$.getJSON(url, function(tweet){
    $title = tweet[0].text;
    $message = tweet[1].text;
});
```

Comment: If this method works, which I have not tried, you could also just do a .split on the resulting string. For example, tweet[0].text.split(':'); which would return an array split at the :. I recommend using something different than :, however, in case someone uses a : in their status. Perhaps a | ?

Comment: Yeah you could do it all in one tweet, I just thought it might be simpler and less error prone to do it as two.  It deffinately works though as I have literally just been coding it about an hour ago on my website. :)

Comment: Very cool... I am going to give this a try real quick.  Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: I added an update to my post, let me know if it looks right to you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can make a request to the Twitter API to retrieve the 'timeline' for a given user.

> https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=USERNAME&count=1

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Edit: See [@Jon Taylor's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11421540#143327) for an implementation

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't going to be what you're going for, but here's a twitter widget I coded a while back. I've included the JS that the client can edit (top section) along with the compressed "gears and working parts" that they shouldn't edit, along with the HTML container. Obviously you'll need to add your own CSS and customize as needed.

Here's a working example: ( [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXDAs/) )

```
/* Twitter initiates. Enter your username here. */
    jQuery(function($){
          $(".tweeter_widget").tweet({
            join_text: "auto",
            username: "YOUR_USERNAME",
            avatar_size: null,
            count: 1,
            auto_join_text_default: "",
            auto_join_text_ed: "",
            auto_join_text_ing: "",
            auto_join_text_reply: "",
            auto_join_text_url: "",
            loading_text: "loading tweets..."
          })
          // if tweet is over 106 characters long, set the line-height so that the text will wrap to the next line and appear centered in the tweet bar.
          .bind("loaded", function() {
        var $tweet = $(".tweet_first"); // maybe using  $(this)  is better
        var $numWords = $tweet.text().length;
        if (($numWords >= 1) && ($numWords > 106)) {
            $tweet.css({ "line-height": "24px !important" });
        }
        else {
            $tweet.css({ "line-height": "50px !important" });
        }
      });
});
```

Compressed code to go along with:

```
//twitter widget
(function(a){a.fn.tweet=function(b){function l(b){var d={};d.item=b;d.source=b.source;d.screen_name=b.from_user||b.user.screen_name;d.avatar_size=c.avatar_size;d.avatar_url=j(b.profile_image_url||b.user.profile_image_url);d.retweet=typeof b.retweeted_status!="undefined";d.tweet_time=g(b.created_at);d.join_text=c.join_text=="auto"?i(b.text):c.join_text;d.tweet_id=b.id_str;d.twitter_base="http://"+c.twitter_url+"/";d.user_url=d.twitter_base+d.screen_name;d.tweet_url=d.user_url+"/status/"+d.tweet_id;d.reply_url=d.twitter_base+"intent/tweet?in_reply_to="+d.tweet_id;d.retweet_url=d.twitter_base+"intent/retweet?tweet_id="+d.tweet_id;d.favorite_url=d.twitter_base+"intent/favorite?tweet_id="+d.tweet_id;d.retweeted_screen_name=d.retweet&&b.retweeted_status.user.screen_name;d.tweet_relative_time=h(d.tweet_time);d.tweet_raw_text=d.retweet?"RT @"+d.retweeted_screen_name+" "+b.retweeted_status.text:b.text;d.tweet_text=a([d.tweet_raw_text]).linkUrl().linkUser().linkHash()[0];d.tweet_text_fancy=a([d.tweet_text]).makeHeart().capAwesome().capEpic()[0];d.user=e('<a class="tweet_user" href="{user_url}" target="_blank">{screen_name}</a>',d);d.join=c.join_text?e(' <span class="tweet_join">{join_text}</span> ',d):" ";d.avatar=d.avatar_size?e('<a class="tweet_avatar" href="{user_url}" target="_blank"><img src="{avatar_url}" height="{avatar_size}" width="{avatar_size}" alt="{screen_name}\'s avatar" title="{screen_name}\'s avatar" border="0"/></a>',d):"";d.time=e('<span class="tweet_time"><a href="{tweet_url}" target="_blank" title="view tweet on twitter">{tweet_relative_time}</a></span>',d);d.text=e('<span class="tweet_text">{tweet_text_fancy}</span>',d);d.reply_action=e('<a class="tweet_action tweet_reply" href="{reply_url}" target="_blank">reply</a>',d);d.retweet_action=e('<a class="tweet_action tweet_retweet" href="{retweet_url}" target="_blank">retweet</a>',d);d.favorite_action=e('<a class="tweet_action tweet_favorite" href="{favorite_url}" target="_blank">favorite</a>',d);return d}function k(){var a="https:"==document.location.protocol?"https:":"http:";var b=c.fetch===null?c.count:c.fetch;if(c.list){return a+"//"+c.twitter_api_url+"/1/"+c.username[0]+"/lists/"+c.list+"/statuses.json?page="+c.page+"&per_page="+b+"&callback=?"}else if(c.favorites){return a+"//"+c.twitter_api_url+"/favorites/"+c.username[0]+".json?page="+c.page+"&count="+b+"&callback=?"}else if(c.query===null&&c.username.length==1){return a+"//"+c.twitter_api_url+"/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name="+c.username[0]+"&count="+b+(c.retweets?"&include_rts=1":"")+"&page="+c.page+"&callback=?"}else{var d=c.query||"from:"+c.username.join(" OR from:");return a+"//"+c.twitter_search_url+"/search.json?&q="+encodeURIComponent(d)+"&rpp="+b+"&page="+c.page+"&callback=?"}}function j(a){return"https:"==document.location.protocol?a.replace(/^http:/,"https:"):a}function i(a){if(a.match(/^(@([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)) .*/i)){return c.auto_join_text_reply}else if(a.match(d)){return c.auto_join_text_url}else if(a.match(/^((\w+ed)|just) .*/im)){return c.auto_join_text_ed}else if(a.match(/^(\w*ing) .*/i)){return c.auto_join_text_ing}else{return c.auto_join_text_default}}function h(a){var b=arguments.length>1?arguments[1]:new Date;var c=parseInt((b.getTime()-a)/1e3,10);var d="";if(c<60){d=c+" seconds ago"}else if(c<120){d="a minute ago"}else if(c<45*60){d=parseInt(c/60,10).toString()+" minutes ago"}else if(c<2*60*60){d="an hour ago"}else if(c<24*60*60){d=""+parseInt(c/3600,10).toString()+" hours ago"}else if(c<48*60*60){d="a day ago"}else{d=parseInt(c/86400,10).toString()+" days ago"}return" "+d}function g(a){return Date.parse(a.replace(/^([a-z]{3})( [a-z]{3} \d\d?)(.*)( \d{4})$/i,"$1,$2$4$3"))}function f(b,c){return function(){var d=[];this.each(function(){d.push(this.replace(b,c))});return a(d)}}function e(a,b){if(typeof a==="string"){var c=a;for(var d in b){var e=b[d];c=c.replace(new RegExp("{"+d+"}","g"),e===null?"":e)}return c}else return a(b)}var c=a.extend({username:null,list:null,favorites:false,query:null,avatar_size:null,count:3,fetch:null,page:1,retweets:true,intro_text:null,outro_text:null,join_text:null,auto_join_text_default:"i said,",auto_join_text_ed:"i",auto_join_text_ing:"i am",auto_join_text_reply:"i replied to",auto_join_text_url:"i was looking at",loading_text:null,refresh_interval:null,twitter_url:"twitter.com",twitter_api_url:"api.twitter.com",twitter_search_url:"search.twitter.com",template:"{avatar}{time}{join}{text}",comparator:function(a,b){return b["tweet_time"]-a["tweet_time"]},filter:function(a){return true}},b);var d=/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi;a.extend({tweet:{t:e}});a.fn.extend({linkUrl:f(d,function(a){var b=/^[a-z]+:/i.test(a)?a:"http://"+a;return'<a href="'+b+'" target="_blank">'+a+"</a>"}),linkUser:f(/@(\w+)/gi,'@<a href="http://'+c.twitter_url+'/$1" target="_blank">$1</a>'),linkHash:f(/(?:^| )[\#]+([\w\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0600-\u06ff]+)/gi,' <a href="http://'+c.twitter_search_url+"/search?q=&tag=$1&lang=all"+(c.username&&c.username.length==1?"&from="+c.username.join("%2BOR%2B"):"")+'" target="_blank">#$1</a>'),capAwesome:f(/\b(awesome)\b/gi,'<span class="awesome">$1</span>'),capEpic:f(/\b(epic)\b/gi,'<span class="epic">$1</span>'),makeHeart:f(/(<)+[3]/gi,"<tt class='heart'>&#x2665;</tt>")});return this.each(function(b,d){var f=a('<ul class="tweet_list">').appendTo(d);var g='<p class="tweet_intro">'+c.intro_text+"</p>";var h='<p class="tweet_outro">'+c.outro_text+"</p>";var i=a('<p class="loading">'+c.loading_text+"</p>");if(c.username&&typeof c.username=="string"){c.username=[c.username]}if(c.loading_text)a(d).append(i);a(d).bind("tweet:load",function(){a.getJSON(k(),function(b){if(c.loading_text)i.remove();if(c.intro_text)f.before(g);f.empty();var j=a.map(b.results||b,l);j=a.grep(j,c.filter).sort(c.comparator).slice(0,c.count);f.append(a.map(j,function(a){return"<li>"+e(c.template,a)+"</li>"}).join("")).children("li:first").addClass("tweet_first").end().children("li:odd").addClass("tweet_even").end().children("li:even").addClass("tweet_odd");if(c.outro_text)f.after(h);a(d).trigger("loaded").trigger(j.length===0?"empty":"full");if(c.refresh_interval){window.setTimeout(function(){a(d).trigger("tweet:load")},1e3*c.refresh_interval)}})}).trigger("tweet:load")})}})(jQuery);
```

and then HTML container:

```
<section class="footer-top">
            <div class="f-top-inner"  id="follow-me"> <a class="twit-logo" href="https://twitter.com/intent/follow?original_referer=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fabout%2Fresources%2Fbuttons&screen_name=YOUR_USER_NAME&source=followbutton&variant=2.0" title="Follow Us" target="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social', 'Social_Click', 'Twitter']);"></a> 
                <!--tweet position-->
                <div class="tweeter_widget" id="tweetDiv"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
```